# Azure Table Storage row Replace() call makes next read slower

Tags: c#, .net, performance, azure, azure-table-storage

I have implemented a text message module within my app to send receive messages among users just like a simple email application. I'm using Azure Storage Table as the storage.

When reading the inbox, I'm updating `MarkAsRead` field for new messages when reading, the next immediate reading from the Storage Table within the same PartitionKey takes long time to read the record and then on wards reading is fast until next update done to the Storage Table.

I have tried out with `TableOperation.Replace` and `TableOperation.Merge`, both gave me the same performances.

What is the cause for this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question to show a sample table entity, along with the query you're doing. That way, we can see which properties you're querying (there's a difference if you use partitionkey/rowkey or other properties).

Answer (score 0):

> the next immediate reading from the Storage Table within the same PartitionKey takes long time to read the record and then on wards reading is fast until next update done to the Storage Table.

You can try to [turn on Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-monitor-storage-account) for your table service to collect metrics and logs, which can help you troubleshoot the issue.

You can check the logs of table service in container **$logs**, and you can find ***end-to-end-latency-in-ms*** and ***server-latency-in-ms*** info from log entry.

- **end-to-end-latency-in-ms**: The total time in milliseconds to perform
  the requested operation, including the time to read the incoming
  request and send the response to the requester.
- **server-latency-in-ms**: The total time in milliseconds to perform the
  requested operation. This value does not include network latency (the
  time to read the incoming request and send the response to the
  requester).

For detailed information about the format of log entries that Storage Logging writes, see [Storage Analytics Log Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Storage-Analytics-Log-Format?redirectedfrom=MSDN).